# 'chkHidePointLabels' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a checkbox in a aspx file and i want to use that checkbox in my vb file. I am getting a error and I don't know how I am suppost to declare it or what the "protection level" part indicates

aspx file:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkHidePointLabels" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text="Hide point labels"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
```

aspx.vb:

```
 If chkHidePointLabels.Checked Then
            Session("ShowHidePointLabels") = "HIDE"
            chkHidePointLabels.Checked = True
        Else
            Session("ShowHidePointLabels") = "SHOW"
            chkHidePointLabels.Checked = False
        End If
```

Error:

```
'chkHidePointLabels' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Comment: Check the designer file and make sure that the ID is correct. The syntax looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

Check the designer file and make sure that the ID is correct, if it's not in the designer then you will need to declare it in your code behind. Something along the lines of:

```
Public WithEvents chkHidePointLabels As Checkbox
```